# How can I rename a remote master with Git without server access?

Tags: git

Have a git repo with just the original master branch.
What to create something like  e.g.
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model

Anyhow the current master has been used as develop branch.
So would like to rename the remote master to develop but get the following error each time.

I am currently doing the follwing:

```
git branch -m master develop
```

and get

```
remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
remote: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.
remote:
remote: You can set 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' configuration variable to
remote: 'warn' or 'ignore' in the remote repository to allow deleting the
remote: current branch, with or without a warning message.
remote:
remote: To squelch this message, you can set it to 'refuse'.
remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
To C:/somewhere
 ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
```

I do not have appropriate access to ssh in to the server and change 'receive.denyDeleteCurrent' as indicated and described here e.g.
http://dcsg.me/tutorials/how-to-allow-remove-master-branch-from-git/

What option do I have from my local cloned repo side?

**EDIT**
Need to retain all commit history.

Comment: As [zeal answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51708850/1256452), you should probably simply *add* a `develop` branch. You could potentially retract `master` as well but you need to know what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry should have said, I want to preserve all commit history. Hence the idea of renaming master (edited post to reflect).

Comment: Branch names are just pointers to commits. As long as some name points to the commit, the commit remains. Adding a `develop` that points to the same commit as `master` causes all those commits to be on both branches. New commits added to `develop` at that point will be only on `develop` until and unless they are merged into `master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new branch first, switch it it, then delete the old branch.

`git checkout -b [name_of_your_new_branch]` -- create

`git checkout [name_of_your_new_branch]` --switch

`git push origin [name_of_your_new_branch]` --push to server

Now you should be able to delete your branch.

Granted, you are trying to delete what seems like master which is a bad idea. You most likely just want to do the above with the branch name `develop`, and not delete `master`.

You will always have multiple branches.

Comment: Sorry should have said, I want to preserve all commit history. Hence the idea of renaming master (edited post to reflect).

Comment: Creating a branch does preserve commit history.

Comment: Read through the link you provided. You always have multiple branches. You branch off `master` as `develop`. Once `develop` is good then you merge it back into `master`. This always retains the history of all the branches. Even after a merge or branch.